# How to change the color of indicator

Tags: visualforce, fields, required-field

How can we show indicator for required field in VF page, There is always a red indicator , I want to have some other color indicator against the fields, I am using outputfield to show the values and not successful to show any kind of indicator except having onemore field outputtext but it seems not working for me

Example :

```
   <script>
    .myRequired {background-color: #CC0000;margin-right: 2px;display: inline;width: 3px;float: left;}
    </script>
    <apex:form>
      <apex:inlineeditsupport ShowOnEdit="save,cancel" event="ondblclick">
      <apex:pageblock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">

         <apex:outputfield value="{!Account.NaicsCode}" styleclass="myRequired"/> 
<apex:outputfield value="{!Account.NaicsDesc}" styleclass="myRequired"/
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
    <apex:form>
```

It does not show that red bar beside outputfield as it is inline editing, I cannot use the inputfield.

If I use outputtext then it does show the red bar.

[How to get red required field indicator to show when using inline edit support?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10786/how-to-get-red-required-field-indicator-to-show-when-using-inline-edit-support)

I have referred the following link but it does not solve the issue of having a required indicator for outputfield

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get red required field indicator to show when using inline edit support?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10786/how-to-get-red-required-field-indicator-to-show-when-using-inline-edit-support)

Comment: I have referred the following link but it does not solve the issue of having a required indicator for outputfield

Comment: You can;t without rolling your own which it the point of the post. It is not "natively" possible.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of css and the proper tag: Example below

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<style>
.requiredBlock{
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
</style>

<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock >
<apex:pageblocksection >
<apex:inputField value="{!account.name}"/>
</apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

Of course if you get more specific with your selectors you may not need the !important flag

Comment: Thanks, Yes I was using this kind of inline css
 <style>
    .mycs {background-color: #CC0000;margin-right: 2px;display: inline;width: 3px;}
    </style>  
but the problem it is not reflecting on outputfield, though it does show on outputtext.

Comment: Required marks in SF only show up in inputFields. You can roll your own if you need it on an output field so your question is a bit unclear. Post an example as an edit to your question of this page that is doing what you want just with the wrong color

Comment: Done, Iam using outputField field due to inlined editing functionality, I want to place a green or red bar beside the outputField field